# jquery each and a JSON string

Tags: jquery, json

Ok I think I am having a bad moment. Usually I can iterate over JSON without issue.

Here is a Sample String

```
{
    "service 1": {
        "admin": {},
        "list": [
            "1"
        ],
        "info": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "details": "Failed",
                "curr-status": "Warning",
                "curr-status-class": "warning"
            }
        ],
        "status": [
            {}
        ]
    },
    "service 2": {
        "admin": {},
        "list": [
            "1"
        ],
        "info": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "details": "Failed",
                "curr-status": "Warning",
                "curr-status-class": "warning"
            }
        ],
        "status": [
            {}
        ]
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is be able to do an $.each() on every service then make a pretty list out of it, and eventually sort based on etc..

My last failed attempt at iterating through it is:

```
$('.refreshAllb').click(function()
{
    $.post('services.json', {"x":"blank"}, function(data)
    {
        $('body').html('');
        $.each(data, function(i)
        {
            $.each(data[i], function(x, z)
            {
                $('body').append(x.z+"<br>");
            });
        });
    }, "json");

});
```

I have looped over various concepts of running each() with an each() to being a lone each. All I keep returning is object object or undefined. So I know I am in the ballpark but I am not hitting the nail on the head.. ideas?

Comment: right now I am still getting virtually nothing returned. I am getting "o, undefined, undefined, undefined". All I wanna do is print "Service 1", "Service 2" I'd be happy with just that at this point..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.refreshAllb').click(function() {
    $.post('services.json', {"x":"blank"}, function(data) {
        $('body').empty();
        $.each(data, function(serviceName) {
            $.each(this, function(key) {
                $('body').append(serviceName + "." + key + "=" + this + "<br/>");
            });
        });
    }, "json");
});
```

Comment: nice, alright. Now I am getting somewhere. Is there a specific reason as to why my initial approach wasn't working? I usually handle it in similar fashions as per my original post, but this one got me beat. It'd be nice to understand more where the fail aspect of what i was doing comes into play.

Comment: @chris: You need to remind yourself of the behaviour of [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). The first argument passed to the callback is the _key_, and the second is the value, not the other way around. Note that `this` is the same as the second parameter, so you shouldn't need the second parameter in most cases.